# Mapping a many-to-two relationship in fluent-nhibernate

Tags: c#, database, fluent-nhibernate

I'm working with a node/link structure, but I'm having problems mapping it using fluent nhibernate.

This is a simplification of the classes I'm using.

```cs
class Node
{
  public virtual IList Links { get; set; }
}

class Link
{
  public virtual Node StartNode { get; set; }
  public virtual Node EndNode { get; set; }
}
```

A node can have many links connected to it.
A link has to be connected to two nodes.

And I need to know which node is the start node and end node, so they have to be specific. Which is why I can not use a list and limit it to two nodes.

Has anyone come across this problem and found a solution to it?

**Edit:** Clearifying question
I'm not using Automapping, I'm using the explisit mapping methods: References, HasMany and HasManyToMany. Essentially following the methods found in the introductory tutorial: http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Getting_started#Your_first_project

I don't have a database either, I'll create the database schema from the mappings using nhibernate.

What I'm asking is, how do I create a many-to-two relation?

Comment: So what is your question exactly? How you would map Link, Node or both?  Also are you doing automapping or are there existing database tables you are using (if so post the tables)?

Comment: I've updated the question, I hope it clearifies things :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there's not a special many to two relationship but what you'd probably do is something like this:

```
public class NodeMap : ClassMap<Node>
{
    public NodeMap()
    {
        //Id and any other fields mapped in node

        HasMany(x => x.Links);
    }
}

public class LinkMap : ClassMap<Link>
{
    public LinkMap()
    {
        //Id and any other fields mapped in node

        References(x => x.StartNode);
        References(x => x.EndNode);
    }
}
```

Again this is just a brief overview above.  You will probably need additional mapping attributes if you want to for example cascade any create/update/delete actions.